# Can the generators of SU(4) be divided into 3 distinct subgroups?

Tags: group-theory

Given the 15 [generators (see last page)](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpsroc.phys.ntu.edu.tw%2Fcjp%2Fdownload.php%3Ftype%3Dfull%26vol%3D3%26num%3D1%26page%3D45&ei=0480VOesF_C1sQSKtoEo&usg=AFQjCNHqNqa0VI7lhPzZ-trIkKutaCKJww&bvm=bv.76943099,d.cWc&cad=rja) of SU(4), is it possible to divide them into 3 subgroups of 5 elements?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good. As this question appears to be homework, please consider reading [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/8348) for information about asking _effective_ homework-related questions. Cheers!